# Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2 +1}$ converges or not.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2 +1}$ converges or not.

** My trial **
I tried dividing $\frac{\ln(n)}{n^2 +1}$ by $1/n^2$ and finding the limit which was $\infty$ so I could not use the limit comparison test and this idea did not work.

Could anyone give me a hint for studying the convergence of this series?

Comment: do you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^2+1}$$?

Comment: Hint: Use the inequality $\ln n < n$ in the following way $\ln n = 2 \ln  \sqrt{n} < 2 \sqrt{n}$

Comment: @clathratus yes sorry I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare with $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1.5}}$$

Comment: you mean comparison not limit comparison?

Comment: Either way. This series converges. With direct comparison, the OP series has smaller terms (eventually). With a limit comparison, the ratio of the OP terms to the terms here converges to $0$. Either implies the OP series converges.

Comment: but if I use the direct comparison test how can I compare them?

Comment: You would need to know that (eventually) $\ln(n)<n^{0.5}$. There are proofs out there that (eventually) $\ln(n)<n^{\varepsilon}$ for any positive $\varepsilon$.

Comment: are they difficult proofs?

Comment: For example, $\ln(n)/n^{0.5}$. What is the limit of this as $n\to\infty$? By L'Hospital, it is the same as the limit of $1/(0.5n^{0.5})$, which is $0$. So for large enough $n$, $\ln(n)/n^{0.5}<1$. So for large enough $n$, $\ln(n)<n^{0.5}$.